# How to access instance properties of an NSWindow loaded from an nib file from another class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

While I have been programming on Linux, BSD and Windows for many years, I'm new to Mac development and I think I'm not *'getting it'* when it comes to Mac / Objective-C / Xcode development patterns.

I have created a new window in Interface Builder called `Window2`.  This window was an object added to `MainMenu.xib` and is not a separate xib file.

There are several controls on `Window2`, mostly textfields and buttons.  I have connected these controls as IBOutlet properties in the `.h` file of my window controller.  I'm able to successfully access these properties within the instance itself, however I can't access them from another class or even from a class method within the same class.

I thought about using a global NSMutableDictionary to store the pointers for each of the controls, but that seems 'hackish'.  Hours of internet and Stack Overflow searches have not provided any useful clues.

Is there some way that meets good programming practices to access `Window2`'s instance properties from a class method or another class?

I'm using Objective-C with Xcode 9.3 on macOS 10.13.4.

**Window2Controller.h**

```
@interface Window2Controller

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField * textHostName;

@end
```

Below is what I'd like to do and probably not working code:

**OtherClass.m**

```
#import "Window2Controller.h"

@implementation OtherClass

- (void)printTextHostNameValue
{
    NSString * txtHost = [Window2Controller textHostName] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"txtHost is: %@", txtHost);
}
```

Comment: Class methods are the same as C++ static methods, you can’t access instance data from a class method.  Also, specify _how_ you’re trying to access the properties from a different class (though that seems wrong to begin with, OO wise), are you familiar with C++, java or even C#? You need some object oriented background to use objc.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Yes, I've developed open-source software using C++ and C.  Sometimes there are situations where the stiff OO principles need workarounds, and this is one such time.

Comment: [This document about MVC by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) is a must read to get the core concepts of OO in Cocoa. Sure it looks complex and a lot at first look, but it's actually accessible. I also recommend you look into the "delegate" pattern (to communicate from a class to another).

Comment: @Moritz I did read the MVC article before, but the delegate information proved to be the most useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Moritz's helpful advice and consulting the Apple documentation, I found a solution to this issue.  I used `[[NSApp keyWindow] delegate]` to find my window's delegate and I'm able to access the IBOutlet properties on it.

**Window2Delegate.h**

```
@interface Window2Controller

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField * textHostName;

@end
```

*After* my new window is key:

**OtherClass.m**

```
#import "Window2Controller.h"

@implementation OtherClass

- (void)printTextHostNameValue
{
    id del = [[NSApp keyWindow] delegate];
    NSString * hostText = [[del textHostName] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"hostText is: %@", hostText);
}  

@end
```